# MariaDB ERROR InnoDB: Expected tablespace id % but found % in the file .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

Tengo instalado XAMPP 7.4.23 en mi computador (Windows 10).

Todos los días inicio el Panel de Control de XAMPP para habilitar Apache y Mysql (MariaDB 10), y así poder trabajar en modo local mis desarrollos web.

A veces se ha caído, y gracias a los tips de varios sitios (SO incluido) he logrado salvar cada caso.

Pero hoy esto ya ha salido de mis manos, pues no encuentro la solución en internet, o es tan avanzada que no logro comprender lo que leo...

Esto comenzó ayer: Cuando intento iniciar el servicio de Mysql, espera unos segundos y se cae:

[image: Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly]

Y últimamente, en el Log de Mysql, me sale este tipo de mensajes/errores:

> [ERROR] InnoDB: Expected tablespace id % but found % in the file .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd

> [Note] InnoDB: trying to read page [page id: space=130, page number=0] in the background in a non-existing or being-dropped tablespace

Tras varias horas intentando tracear el origen del error, me encontré con que hay dos archivos de la BD `mysql` que son lo que me generan este error: se trata de **innodb_index_stats.ibd** y **innodb_table_stats.ibd**.

Esto lo comprobé tras reemplazar mi carpeta `data` con los contenidos de la carpeta `backup`, tras lo cual comencé a agregar las carpetas de mis BD desde mi carpeta `data` original, pero sin pisar las bases `mysql`, `performance_schema` ni `phpmyadmin` ni los archivos en la raíz de `data`.

De ese modo pude iniciar el servicio Mysql sin problemas, pero al revisar las BD en phpMyAdmin me encontré con todos los fallos propios de la inconsistencia creada al pegar archivos de distintos tiempos (la BD `mysql` no tenía los registros de mis nuevas BD). Entonces fue que comencé a pegar los archivos de las carpetas `mysql` y `performance_schema` desde mi carpeta `data` de respaldo, y yendo archivo por archivo, descubrí que esos archivos que mencioné antes (*innodb_index_stats.ibd* y *innodb_table_stats.ibd*) eran los que hacían caer a mi servidor de BD.

Cabe mencionar que, al revisar mis BD desde phpMyAdmin, aparecen mis BD, y puedo acceder a ellas, incluso se ven sus tablas, pero a éstas le sale vacío el campo "Tipo" (debiera decir InnoDB, pero sale vacío) y lo mismo ocurre con el contador de registros: no sale nada, ni siquiera el cero.

[image: Tablas de la BD]

Y al hacer click en una de ellas, me aparece el error de que la tabla no existe:

[image: Error 1932: Table doesn't exist in engine]

Pero, cuando entro a mis páginas web, sí logran conectarse y obtener los datos, por lo que se cargan correctamente. Por lo que supongo que todo el problema tiene que ver con la definición de las tablas, y no con su manipulación.

La pregunta es ¿algun@ de ustedes tiene alguna idea o puede iluminarme sobre qué pasó, pero sobretodo, cómo puedo reparar estos archivos, para que sean válidos para Mysql, y me permita recuperar el acceso a los datos de mis BD?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Posiblemente tienen un error en la config de MySqli, aquí tengo una posible solución a tu pregunta [MySQL Shutdown Unexpectedly](https://kinsta.com/es/base-de-conocimiento/xampp-mysql-cierra-inesperadamente/)

Comment: @Dev.Fra Gracias por el link. Ya había visitado esas soluciones, sólo que estaba todo en inglés. Pero ya probé todo eso, y nada resultó, por eso vine a preguntar acá, gracias igual.